# Using complex exported resource tags in Puppet 7 - is it possible

Tags: puppet

I need to define a Puppet class and exported resources similarly to
https://serverfault.com/questions/559019/how-to-collect-tagged-exported-resources
with the small variance that I need to add
class app_primary($datacenter_$zone_$tenant_$role) for the satellites servers to join the primary
and then use the same class identifier as a tag like
tag => "$datacenter_$zone_$tenant_$role",
Can you please advise if using such complex tags is possible or I should stick to the KISS principle. Thanks.

Reading from the documentation I should aim for the most unique exported resource tag type possible or work with hiera ( out of my bounds and privileges for the time being ). Therefore decided to ask before digging down further in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to add class app_primary($datacenter_$zone_$tenant_$role) for
> the satellites servers

That doesn't make sense.  The appearance of the `class` keyword suggests that that is the beginning of a class *definition* for class `app_primary`.  The parentheses would then contain a list of class parameters -- names, optionally types, and optionally initial values.  `$datacenter_$zone_$tenant_$role` is not a valid parameter name.  Possibly you want this class to have four distinct parameters here:

```
class app_primary($datacenter, $zone, $tenant, $role) {
  # ...
}
```

> to join the primary and then use the same class
> identifier as a tag like tag => "$datacenter_$zone_$tenant_$role",

Class parameters do not *identify* a class.  The identifier of the class above is `app_primary`.

However, you *can* form a string that concatenates the values of the parameters, and tag resources with it.  The form of the string would be something like this: `"${datacenter}_${zone}_${tenant}_${role}"`.  That tagging would distinguish resources declared by this class with one set of parameter values from resources declared by this class (for a different node) with a different set of parameter values.

> Can
> you please advise if using such complex tags is possible

Certainly it's possible.  And I'm not sure I would characterize the result as "complex".

> or I should
> stick to the KISS principle.

Simplicity is relative.  If you have a simpler alternative in mind then KISS might be something to consider, but until then, it's irrelevant.

Comment: thanks. Ain't easy to land from puppet 3 directly to 7.x in 2 months or so and keep your head sober while mangling several domains in your head. I will put another question for what I my status really is and what I want to achieve.